# How can I merge these two HTML codes?

Tags: html, google-maps, merge

I have one code that shows elevation and another which displays weather information. Is there a way to merge the two codes together so I have one map that has both features? I am using notepad to work on this.

Code 1:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Elevation service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

    var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS
    });
    weatherLayer.setMap(map);

    var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
    cloudLayer.setMap(map);
    }
   var elevator;
   var map;
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var denali = new google.maps.LatLng(60.750000, -139.500000);

   function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: denali,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

     // Create an ElevationService
    elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

    // Add a listener for the click event and call getElevation on that location
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);
    }

    function getElevation(event) {

    var locations = [];

    // Retrieve the clicked location and push it on the array
    var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
    locations.push(clickedLocation);

    // Create a LocationElevationRequest object using the array's one value
   var positionalRequest = {
    'locations': locations
    }

    // Initiate the location request
    elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

      // Retrieve the first result
      if (results[0]) {

        // Open an info window indicating the elevation at the clicked position
        infowindow.setContent('The elevation at this point <br>is ' + results[0].elevation + ' meters.');
        infowindow.setPosition(clickedLocation);
        infowindow.open(map);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

AND Code 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather layer</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=weather"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.750000, -139.500000),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS
  });
  weatherLayer.setMap(map);

  var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
  cloudLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to put the code into a seperate .js file, and link it in. That way, the code would be right next to each other, and hence you could get both effects, which other wise would not work. You are already linking a script file from google - all you would need is to put the code of yours into a .js file, and link it in the same way